# Is there a way to set AdministrationQueue property when using net.msmq (MSMQ) binding on WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

We are are thinking how to monitor MSMQ queues that are used from WCF services (with net.msmq binding). Searching for alternatives like Journals, triggers or [Administration queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the last one seems to be more logic as you can get several message-level events reported to that other queue and not only "message received", so we think we can track messages or higher-level operations.

Anyway, WCF's net.msmq binding doesn't seem to have a way to manipulate acknowledges or [AdministrationQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.administrationqueue%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property of the messages send through.

Is there a way to enable Acknowledges and AdministrationQueue from WCF binding/behavior? If it is not, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible with `NetMsmqBinding`. It should be possible with `MsmqIntegrationBinding`. Once you are using this binding you can use `OperationContract`'s `IncommingMessageProperties` or `OutgoingMessageProperties` and get access to the instance of `MsmqIntegrationMesssageProperty`. Then you will have control over all properties exposed on MSMQ message including `AdministrationQueue` and `Acknowledgment`.